# is there a way to make ggplot2() visualize a model with two dependents and interactive predictors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

is there a way to make ggplot2() visualize a model with two dependents and multiple interactive predictors?

Lets say I have a model:

```
lm_comb1 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ SAT_AVG*TUITIONFEE_OUT*AVGFACSAL* RET_FT4_POOLED*INEXPFTE*C100_4_POOLED,data = training_set_NORM_sample)
```

And here's some data:

```
training_set_NORM_sample <- dput(training_set_NORM_sample[1:35, ]) structure(list(MD_EARN_WNE_P10 = c(0.309428236924474, 0.29019425130815, 0.340154827610924, 0.131137552863594, 0.202243566769407, 0.130145987145485, 0.0872936229183093, 0.141208515518601, 0.118486130026521, 0.12969201729864, 0.113038491864382, 0.29583303466896, 0.129966788521731, 0.190655389099945, 0.32601008290923, 0.319511146154398, 0.177800874489284, 0.277662294220247, 0.0420997300074069, 0.111043413853248, 0.167395407736602, 0.139046185458629, 0.227701717917473, 0.205074905024729, 0.278653859938356, 0.130062361121067, 0.092848780254701, 0.128198695434019, 0.35046472176427, 0.229899887702196, 0.292464100542374, 1, 0.373019855207512, 0.268797935631854, 0.421379590471412 ), SAT_AVG = c(0.709756097560976, 0.639024390243902, 0.686585365853659, 0.401219512195122, 0.413414634146341, 0.423170731707317, 0.370731707317073, 0.523170731707317, 0.485365853658537, 0.501219512195122, 0.332926829268293, 0.592682926829268, 0.417073170731707, 0.35609756097561, 0.601219512195122, 0.598780487804878, 0.521951219512195, 0.629268292682927, 0.29390243902439, 0.55, 0.548780487804878, 0.353658536585366, 0.569512195121951, 0.715853658536585, 0.609756097560976, 0.376829268292683, 0.396341463414634, 0.424390243902439, 0.498780487804878, 0.56219512195122, 0.43780487804878, 1, 0.525609756097561, 0.302439024390244, 0.495121951219512), TUITIONFEE_OUT = c(0.377600752915868, 0.490739807065309, 0.505428388961716, 0.357298914322208, 0.442842257403113, 0.33259386239118, 0.319989244059023, 0.383348458875332, 0.4315485193775, 0.32217404456993, 0.318308628281402, 0.534435817283453, 0.263150818459884, 0.362407986286175, 0.476925145373265, 0.59944203556183, 0.472084971933717, 0.417162448321065, 0.232899734462707, 0.248899196665658, 0.251218446438775, 0.262176061308864, 0.330829215824678, 0.782326644482538, 0.447346307687137, 0.418473328627609, 0.285872743773319, 0.210581156935901, 0.658297200094115, 0.687808813149138, 0.56858592988471, 0.899969748916003, 0.728244428758697, 0.297721085005546, 0.306309031629189), AVGFACSAL = c(0.36104042974272, 0.395137121854679, 0.420412779191405, 0.152558665535765, 0.190839694656489, 0.224257845631891, 0.179700310998021, 0.106813683912921, 0.251795306757139, 0.284591461690698, 0.108283856375459, 0.326604467062482, 0.189652247667515, 0.221713316369805, 0.476844783715013, 0.449703138252757, 0.185128640090472, 0.381962114786542, 0.141588917161436, 0.221260955612101, 0.215889171614362, 0.11314673452078, 0.230251625671473, 0.235849590048063, 0.213740458015267, 0.193214588634436, 0.122420130053718, 0.20056545094713, 0.322533220243144, 0.247271699180096, 0.368221656771275, 0.977777777777778, 0.401413627367826, 0.367825841108284, 0.42199604184337), RET_FT4_POOLED = c(0.807788198978986, 0.861569512050338, 0.900035616763623, 0.504333372907515, 0.59028849578535, 0.720408405556215, 0.587914044877122, 0.718390122284222, 0.713403775376944, 0.71827139973881, 0.669595156120147, 0.889113142585777, 0.700581740472516, 0.681704855752107, 0.869167754956666, 0.799952510981835, 0.649412323400214, 0.820847678974237, 0.669595156120147, 0.724088804463968, 0.706874035379318, 0.505876765997863, 0.828802089516799, 0.858482725869643, 0.785943250623293, 0.664846254303692, 0.421108868574142, 0.60845304523329, 0.779176065534845, 0.825952748426926, 0.74154101863944, 0.987771577822629, 0.811112430250505, 0.845779413510626, 0.870948593137837), INEXPFTE = c(0.0462962253598817, 0.0577496188586444, 0.0476445847282979, 0.0263236522152165, 0.0314566111745283, 0.0329658543312214, 0.0389032322319178, 0.0382596970788101, 0.0737077584291613, 0.036421025212788, 0.0401060300776073, 0.100889457515188, 0.03451340315179, 0.0730718844088287, 0.109469926223291, 0.0868466011384443, 0.0815297749925304, 0.0664679879566993, 0.0396233787127765, 0.0208152977499253, 0.0442966697055827, 0.00727807613633752, 0.0612201120057612, 0.0886086616767155, 0.0546238766864068, 0.0409564158156425, 0.0186471971745742, 0.0292272215369765, 0.06528051237656, 0.0768718062652744, 0.0510537888132139, 0.787104781312965, 0.0540109860643995, 0.0352105662343234, 0.0351416160393476 ), C100_4_POOLED = c(0.242140845070423, 0.533295774647887, 0.531830985915493, 0.11369014084507, 0.377577464788732, 0.18230985915493, 0.193464788732394, 0.378366197183099, 0.312225352112676, 0.200112676056338, 0.248112676056338, 0.694760563380282, 0.224901408450704, 0.32056338028169, 0.532845070422535, 0.494760563380282, 0.478197183098592, 0.504338028169014, 0.128338028169014, 0.338704225352113, 0.251267605633803, 0.106929577464789, 0.495887323943662, 0.711098591549296, 0.632, 0.388169014084507, 0.339154929577465, 0.279211267605634, 0.489915492957746, 0.597521126760563, 0.412957746478873, 0.894760563380282, 0.698816901408451, 0.114591549295775, 0.21487323943662), X40.year.NPV = c(0.300526315789474, 0.263157894736842, 0.312631578947368, 0.108421052631579, 0.178947368421053, 0.122105263157895, 0.0831578947368421, 0.127894736842105, 0.105789473684211, 0.125789473684211, 0.0784210526315789, 0.25, 0.123684210526316, 0.130526315789474, 0.326315789473684, 0.31, 0.163157894736842, 0.267368421052632, 0.0421052631578947, 0.107894736842105, 0.156842105263158, 0.127894736842105, 0.208421052631579, 0.187368421052632, 0.251052631578947, 0.126842105263158, 0.0794736842105263, 0.121052631578947, 0.316842105263158, 0.183684210526316, 0.263157894736842, 1, 0.337368421052632, 0.281052631578947, 0.418421052631579)), row.names = c(NA, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a question about `ggplot2`'s functionality, so it doesn't particularly matter *which type* of plot we make; I'm trying to determine how (whether?) `ggplot2` handles a model with multiple dependent variables and multiple, interactive predictors.

Comment: This is not really about what ggplot can do. It's about what it is possible to represent in _any_ kind of plot. A model with two d.vs and 5 i.vs is a 7-dimensional structure (it's the best fitting 6 dimensional hypervolume to approximate a cloud of points in a 7 dimensional hypervolume). There are ways to see some aspects of the model, by using two plotting axes, colour, facets, multiple lines, "slices" through the model at the mean of some of its covariates, etc, but it is simply not even nearly possible to see the whole model in ggplot - or any other tool (in this 3 dimensional universe)

Comment: Thanks, @AllanCameron. All things being equal, I do prefer restricting my work to this 3 dimensional universe! But a follow-up: suppose I trim down to only two interactive predictors? Thanks again.

Comment: That made me chuckle! Yes, it's possible to draw the output of a two-dv lm in ggplot - see below.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @AllanCameron. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to show the output of an `lm` with two dependent variables with a single predictor variable.

Let's create an example data set to demonstrate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

dv1 <- rnorm(100, seq(1, 5, length = 100)) * 0.25
dv2 <- rnorm(100, seq(5, 1, length = 100)) * 0.7
iv1 <- 1:100

df <- data.frame(dv1, dv2, iv1)

head(df)
#>          dv1      dv2 iv1
#> 1 0.09338655 3.065743   1
#> 2 0.30601184 3.501198   2
#> 3 0.06129487 2.805789   3
#> 4 0.67912323 3.525772   4
#> 5 0.37278098 2.928659   5
#> 6 0.09538795 4.595687   6
```

And now me make our model:

```r
mod <- lm(cbind(dv1, dv2) ~ iv1, data = df)
```

We can get predictions for both dvs from our model in a data frame like so:

```
pred <- as.data.frame(predict(mod))
pred$iv1 <- df$iv1
```

Now we can plot both the original points and the prediction lines by pivoting both the original and prediction data frames to long format:

```r
ggplot(pivot_longer(df, 1:2), aes(iv1, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = pivot_longer(pred, 1:2), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>